# why i can't create pods a a user with enough permissions in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am following a tutorial regarding RBAC, I think I understand the main idea but I don't get why this is failing:

```sh
kc auth can-i "*" pod/compute --as deploy@test.com
no

kc create clusterrole deploy --verb="*" --resource=pods --resource-name=compute
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/deploy created

kc create clusterrolebinding deploy --user=deploy@test.com --clusterrole=deploy
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/deploy created

# this tells me that deploy@test.com should be able to create a pod named compute
kc auth can-i "*" pod/compute --as deploy@test.com
yes

# but it fails when trying to do so
kc run compute --image=nginx --as deploy@test.com
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "deploy@test.com" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

the namespace name should be irrelevant afaik, since this is a clusterrole.

Comment: What does the Audit Log report as the rejection criterion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting the `create` permission to a specific resource name is not supported.

This is from the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources):

> Note: You cannot restrict create or deletecollection requests by resourceName. For create, this limitation is because the object name is not known at authorization time.

This means the `ClusterRole` you created doesn't allow you to create any Pod.
You need to have another `ClusterRole` assigned where you don't specify the resource name.